# bar graph plot with different colors for one series (achartengine)

Tags: android, achartengine

I would like to change the color of different bars for a series.

I have a bar graph that has thirty vertical bars representing different frequencies, but I would like to change the color of the bar for different ranges of frequencies. For eg, the first ten bars are green color, followed by next ten bars being yellow color, and the last ten bars red color.

Firstly, is this possible? Secondly, if this is possible could anyone direct me to the relevant function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Each series has its own color, so if you want multiple colors then you need to add multiple series for your bar chart.